# how to send file to printer on centos using php 5.2.4

Tags: php, printing, yii, centos

I have centos 5 with php 5.2.4. I have a file, html, that i want to print. how can I do this on linux. I cannot seem to find anything anywhere about it. its just all windows stuff. I want to print using clients printer. i have tried the following which errors.

```
$handle = printer_open();
        printer_write($handle, "Text to print");
        printer_close($handle);


[Wed May 22 08:00:27 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function printer_open() in /opt/invload/protected/controllers/SiteController.php on line 485, referer: http://portal-dev/invload/index.php?r=site/report&view=report
```

I am using Yii framework and the page I am viewing to print is paginated. doing `window.print` won't print all results so i have made a jquery that would query all results and output to file. now i want to print that file.

in my view

```
<?php 
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Reports';
?>
<style type="text/css">
.odd {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5F1F4;
}
.even {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
}
table tbody tr:hover{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgreen;
}
table tbody tr{
    font-size:10pt;
}
body
{
  margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
}
</style>

<body onload="window.print();window.close();">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>No_</th>
    <th>Pay-to Name</th>
    <th>Order No</th>
    <th width="50px">Vendor Invoice No</th>
    <th>Log Number</th>
    <th width="65px">Posting Date</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$count = 0;
$class= null;
foreach($dataProviderAll->getData() as $q) {
    $class = ($count % 2 === 0) ? 'odd' : 'even';
    $this->renderPartial('_report',array('data'=>$q,'class'=>$class));
    $count++;
}
?>
</table>
</body>
```

in my controller

```
public function actionPrint(){

    $company = Yii::app()->params['currentCompany'];

    $query = Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand("SELECT [No_] AS [no],[Pay-to Name] AS [paytoname],[Order No_] AS [orderno],[Vendor Invoice No_] AS [vendorinvoiceno], [Log Number] AS [lognumber],[Posting Date] AS [postingdate]
            FROM [$company\$Purch_ Inv_ Header] WHERE [Log Number] is not null and [Log Number] not in (
            SELECT [InvoiceLogNo] FROM [$company\$Invoice Image Locations])
            ORDER BY " . $this->order . " " . Yii::app()->session['asc_or_desc'])->queryAll();

    //print_r(count($query));
    $dataProviderAll = new CArrayDataProvider($query);

    $item_count = count($query);
    $pages = new CPagination($item_count);
    $pages->setPageSize($item_count);

    $dataProviderAll->setPagination($pages);


    $print = $this->renderPartial('print',array('dataProviderAll'=>$dataProviderAll),true);
    //print_r($print);
    $file = "/tmp/reports.html";
    file_put_contents($file, $print);

    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$file");
    readfile($file);    
}
```

Comment: You mean a printer on the server side?

Comment: client printer using the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about client-side printing, thus you need to use client-side technologies, i.e. Javascript.

You can do a call to window.print() to print the active window. Check here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

If you wish to have control over what is being printed (e.g. set landscape/portrait printing), you can use a browser plugin. For Firefox, you can do this using jsprintsetup:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

**Edit**: After the update, more information has been added to the question. Adding additional reply below.

In this case, you could open the page with the combined results in a new page and print it. Or, alternatively, you could output all results in an invisible tab and print its contents

**Edit2** (to reply to the comment below):
To open a new window with your data, you can do it from javascript using window.open():

```
window.open("site.com/something.php?param1=1&param2=2");
```

and then from within that window, do:

```
window.print();
window.close();
```

For more info:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

Again, you can use an invisible iframe for this, instead of a new window. The only difference is that you won't be calling window.open(), but you'll print a new iframe to the page. For example, with jQuery you can do:

```
$("<iframe id=\"printFrame\" src=\"" + yourURL + \" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"/>").insertAfter($('body'));
```

Which will create a 0x0 iframe with the contents of the page you want. That page can then print itself with window.print();

Comment: i have updated my code to output files to content and allow user to open it. How can I change my code so it prints and closes without user intervention?